# Использование API Яндекс.Услуги

Tags: php, яндекс-услуги

имеется ключик яндекс.услуг, судя по [документации](http://api.yandex.ru/uslugi/doc/banks-dg/concepts/banks.xml) список банков выдается следующим запросом:

```
http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks ? [key=<API-ключ>] & region=<регион>
```

Вот мой код:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks?[key=***]&region=Moscow");

?>
```

Возвращает следующее:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks?%5Bkey=***%5D®ion=Moscow): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /var/www/neoflat/data/www/neoflatru/calc.php on line 5 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks?%5Bkey=***%5D®ion=Moscow" in /var/www/neoflat/data/www/neoflatru/calc.php on line 5
```

Ошибка 401, судя по документации — ошибка авторизации.

Что я делаю не так, кто подскажет?

Сильно не пинайте, первый раз с API сталкиваюсь.

Comment: @Negatiff Попробуйте открыть этот адрес в браузере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query_data = array(
    'key' => 'API-ключ для доступа к сервисам',
    'region' => 'Moscow'
);
//корректно сформированный запрос
$query = http_build_query($query_data, '', '&amp;');
//url, на который будет отправляться запрос
$service_url = 'http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks';
//корректно сформированный url вместе с запросом
$url = $service_url . '?' . $query;
//Домен, на который вы регестрировали API-ключ
//Вы указывали его в письме яндексу с запросом ключа
$referer = 'URL, для которого действителен указанный API-ключ';
//Отправляем запрос
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Единственное что, выдавал ошибку 400 (отсутствует обязательный параметр), после замены '&amp;' на '&' все отлично заработало!

Еще раз большущее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

"http://api.uslugi.yandex.ru/1.0/banks?[key=***]&region=Moscow"

вообщето без квадратных скобок. обычно квадратными скобками обозначаются необязательные параметры

Comment: Не важно, он и так и так не работает, в саппорте яндекс услуг сказали указать заголовок:
HTTP-заголовок Referer c корректным URL, для которого действителен указанный API-ключ;
Но я не совсем понимаю что там должно быть и как это выглядит, не подскажете?